# Woocommerce error ET_WC_Order::get_total()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce with my Wordpress theme. The website is selling services. The template developer support is dead, they say woocommerce compatibility but there is small bug I need to find the fix myself but I don't know what to do.

When the client tries to add credit to his account he selects the value and goes to next screen where woocommerce payment gateways are shown, they are listed but 'Pay' button its not there. When I look into Wordpress wp-content debug log I got this errors:

[23-Jul-2018 10:15:58 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of ET_WC_Order::get_total() should be compatible with WC_Abstract_Order::get_total($context = 'view') in /home/admin/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite.com/includes/aecore/wc_integration/payment/ET_WC_Order.php on line 3
[23-Jul-2018 10:15:58 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of ET_WC_Package::get_sku() should be compatible with WC_Product::get_sku($context = 'view') in /home/admin/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite.com/includes/aecore/wc_integration/payment/ET_WC_Package.php on line 4

ET_WC_Order.php content:

```
<?php if(class_exists("WC_Abstract_Order")) {
class ET_WC_Order extends WC_Abstract_Order
{
    protected $etOrder;
    protected $cancel_url = "";
    protected $received_url = "";

    public function __construct($order = '')
    {
        $this->post_type = 'order';
        $this->prices_include_tax = get_option('woocommerce_prices_include_tax') == 'yes' ? true : false;
        $this->tax_display_cart = get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_cart');
        $this->display_totals_ex_tax = $this->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ? true : false;
        $this->display_cart_ex_tax = $this->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ? true : false;
        $this->init($order);
    }

    public function get_refunds()
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function get_total_refunded()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param int|object|WC_Order $order
     */
    protected function init($order)
    {
        if (is_numeric($order)) {
            $this->id = absint($order);
            $this->post = get_post($order);
            $this->get_order($this->id);
        } elseif ($order instanceof ET_WC_Order) {
            $this->id = absint($order->id);
            $this->ID = absint($order->id);
            $this->post = $order->post;
            $this->etOrder = $order->etOrder;
            $this->populate($order->etOrder);
        } elseif ($order instanceof AE_Order) {
            $payData = $order->generate_data_to_pay();
            $order->ID = $payData["ID"];
            $this->etOrder = $order;
            $this->populate($order);
            // Billing email cam default to user if set
            if (empty($this->billing_email) && !empty($this->customer_user)) {
                $user = get_user_by('id', $this->customer_user);
                $this->billing_email = $user->user_email;
            }
        } elseif ($order instanceof WP_Post || isset($order->ID)) {
            $this->id = absint($order->ID);
            $this->post = $order;
            $this->get_order($this->id);
        }
    }

    public function get_order($id = 0)
    {
        if (!$id) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->etOrder = new AE_Order($id);
        if ($this->etOrder) {
            $payData = $this->etOrder->generate_data_to_pay();
            $this->etOrder->ID = $payData["ID"];
            $this->populate($this->etOrder);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Populate the order, like convert method
     *
     * @param mixed $result
     */
    public function populate($result)
    {
        $orderData = $result->get_order_data();
        // Standard post data
        $this->id = $result->ID;
        $this->order_date = $orderData['created_date'];
        $this->modified_date = $orderData['created_date'];
        $this->customer_message = '';
        $this->customer_note = '';
        $this->post_status = $orderData['status'];
        // Billing email cam default to user if set
        if (empty($this->billing_email) && !empty($this->customer_user)) {
            $user = get_user_by('id', $this->customer_user);
            $this->billing_email = $user->user_email;
        }
        $this->cancel_url = et_get_page_link('process-payment', array('paymentType' => $orderData['payment']));
        $this->received_url = et_get_page_link('process-payment', array('paymentType' => $orderData['payment']));
    }

    public function get_shipping_address()
    {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Get item of order
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_items($type = '')
    {
        if (empty($type)) {
            $type = array('line_item');
        }
        if (!is_array($type)) {
            $type = array($type);
        }
        $type = array_map('esc_attr', $type);
        $items = array();
        if (in_array('line_item', $type)) {
            $orderData = $this->etOrder->get_order_data();
            if (isset($orderData["products"])) {
                $index = 0;
                foreach ($orderData["products"] as $id => $product) {
                    $items[$index]['name'] = $product['NAME'];
                    $items[$index]['product_id'] = $product['ID'];
                    $items[$index]['type'] = "line_item";
                    $items[$index]['qty'] = $product['QTY'];
                    $items[$index]['tax_class'] = '';
                    $items[$index]['line_subtotal'] = $product['AMT'];
                    $items[$index]['line_subtotal_tax'] = '0';
                    $items[$index]['item_meta'] = array();
                    $index++;
                }
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Get total of order
     * @author : Nguyễn Văn Được
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get_total()
    {
        $orderData = $this->etOrder->get_order_data();
        $total = $orderData["total"];
        return $total;
    }

    /**
     * Get order currency
     * @author : Nguyễn Văn Được
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get_order_currency()
    {
        $orderData = $this->etOrder->get_order_data();
        return $orderData["currency"];
    }

    /**
     * Get products from product item
     * @author : Nguyễn Văn Được
     *
     * @param mixed $item
     *
     * @return bool|\ET_WC_Package
     */
    public function get_product_from_item($item)
    {
        if (!empty($item['product_id'])) {
            $_product = new ET_WC_Package($item['product_id']);
        } else {
            $_product = false;
        }
        return $_product;
    }

    public function get_checkout_order_received_url()
    {
        return $this->received_url;
    }

    public function set_checkout_order_received_url($received_url)
    {
        $this->received_url = $received_url;
    }

    public function get_cancel_order_url($redirect = '')
    {
        return $this->cancel_url;
    }

    public function set_cancel_order_url($cancel_url)
    {
        $this->cancel_url = $cancel_url;
    }

    /**
     * Update order status
     *
     * @param string $new_status
     * @param string $note
     */
    public function update_status($new_status, $note = '',  $manual = false)
    {
        if (!$this->id) {
            return;
        }

        // Standardise status names.
        $new_status = 'wc-' === substr($new_status, 0, 3) ? substr($new_status, 3) : $new_status;
        $old_status = $this->get_status();
        switch (strtoupper($new_status)) {
            case 'COMPLETED':
            case 'PUBLISH':
                $this->post_status = 'publish';
                break;
            case 'PROCESSING' :
            case 'ON-HOLD':
            $this->post_status = 'pending';
                break;
            case 'CANCELLED' :
                $this->post_status = 'draft';
                break;
            default:
                $this->post_status = 'draft';
                break;
        }
        $this->etOrder->post_status = $this->post_status;
        $log = new WC_Logger();
        $log->add('paypal', "Our Debug : " . $this->post_status);
        wp_update_post(array('ID' => $this->etOrder->ID, 'post_status' => $this->post_status));
    }

    public function needs_shipping_address()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function is_editable()
    {
        return parent::is_editable(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }

    public function get_qty_refunded_for_item($item_id, $item_type = 'line_item')
    {
        $qty = 0;
        return $qty;
    }

    public function get_total_refunded_for_item($item_id, $item_type = 'line_item')
    {
        $total = 0;
        return $total * -1;
    }
}
}
```

ET_WC_Package.php content:

```
<?php
if(class_exists("WooCommerce")) {
class ET_WC_Package extends WC_Product
{
    protected $etPaynentPackage;

    function __construct($product, $arg = array())
    {
        $this->product_type = 'pack';
        parent::__construct($product);
    }

    public function get_sku()
    {
        return $this->post->ID;
    }

    public function is_virtual()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function needs_shipping()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function get_permalink() {
        return get_permalink( $this->id );
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP Strict Standards: Declaration of ET_WC_Order::get_total() should
>   be compatible with WC_Abstract_Order::get_total($context = 'view')

Change the `get_total()` function in `ET_WC_Order.php` to be

```
public function get_total($context = 'view')
{
    $orderData = $this->etOrder->get_order_data();
    $total = $orderData["total"];
    return $total;
}
```

> PHP Strict Standards: Declaration of ET_WC_Package::get_sku() should
>   be compatible with WC_Product::get_sku($context = 'view')

Change the `get_sku()` function in `ET_WC_Package.php` to be

```
public function get_sku($context = 'view')
{
    return $this->post->ID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you my dear friend. That solved all my problems.